# RuntimeError: Numpy is not available

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, runtime

I am getting this error `RuntimeError: Numpy is not available`, while trying to run the following line of code:

```py
img = torch.from_numpy(np.array(pic, mode_to_nptype.get(pic.mode, np.uint8), copy=True))
```

Is there a way to solve this without the need to change python version?

Note: my python version is 3.10.

Comment: This topic seems to be about the same issue, yet it hasn't got any good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689095/how-to-solve-the-pytorch-runtimeerror-numpy-is-not-available-without-upgrading

Comment: Is there a way to downgrade the python version without re-installing it all over again? Because I am afraid if I uninstall python all my installed packages will be removed and I will re-install many of them again.

Comment: please use anaconda to manage these package error; trust me its the best

Comment: Thanks, it was fixed with anaconda, maybe because anaconda uses python 3.9 instead of 3.10