RuntimeError: Numpy is not available (transformers)
I basically just want to use the transformers pipeline() to classify data, but independent of which model I try to use, it returns the same error, stating Numpy is not available
Code I'm running:
pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model="AdamLucek/roberta-llama3.1405B-twitter-sentiment")   
sentiment_pipeline('Today is a great day!')
# other model i've tried: 
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline(model="cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest", tokenizer="cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest")
sentiment_pipeline('Today is a great day!')

Error I receive:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 sentiment_pipeline('Today is a great day!')

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\text_classification.py:156, in TextClassificationPipeline.__call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    122 """
    123 Classify the text(s) given as inputs.
    124 
   (...)
    153     If `top_k` is used, one such dictionary is returned per label.
    154 """
    155 inputs = (inputs,)
--> 156 result = super().__call__(*inputs, **kwargs)
    157 # TODO try and retrieve it in a nicer way from _sanitize_parameters.
    158 _legacy = "top_k" not in kwargs

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py:1257, in Pipeline.__call__(self, inputs, num_workers, batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
   1249     return next(
   1250         iter(
   1251             self.get_iterator(
   (...)
   1254         )
   1255     )
   1256 else:
-> 1257     return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py:1265, in Pipeline.run_single(self, inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)
   1263 model_inputs = self.preprocess(inputs, **preprocess_params)
   1264 model_outputs = self.forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
-> 1265 outputs = self.postprocess(model_outputs, **postprocess_params)
   1266 return outputs

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\text_classification.py:208, in TextClassificationPipeline.postprocess(self, model_outputs, function_to_apply, top_k, _legacy)
    204 outputs = model_outputs["logits"][0]
    206 if self.framework == "pt":
    207     # To enable using fp16 and bf16
--> 208     outputs = outputs.float().numpy()
    209 else:
    210     outputs = outputs.numpy()

RuntimeError: Numpy is not available

I already tried simply un- and reinstalling transformers and numpy and for both the most recent versions are installed (and should be compatible).
Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689095/how-to-solve-the-pytorch-runtimeerror-numpy-is-not-available-without-upgrading

Try:
pip install "numpy<2"

then restart the kernel.

I tried and I guess thats the root of the problem. Thoguh, even when I have numpy installed in version 1.26.4 in my active kernel I receive this warning when importing pipeline:
A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run inNumPy 2.0.0 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0. Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

@Leo_Lighthouse This warning is for numpy 2.0. You need to create a fresh virtual environment and install numpy 1.26.4 then try using tranformers.
