Numpy is not available error running spaCy 3.8.2
Getting intermittent "Numpy is not available" error when utilizing the spaCy 3.8.2 library. Has anyone encountered this issue?
Thanks.
============================== Info about spaCy ==============================

spaCy version    3.8.2
Location         C:\Program Files\Python\Lib\site-packages\spacy
Platform         Windows-2022Server-10.0.20348-SP0
Python version   3.12.3
Pipelines        en_core_web_lg (3.8.0), en_core_web_md (3.8.0), en_core_web_sm (3.8.0), en_core_web_trf (3.8.0)


Might be due to numpy version. Does this helps? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689095/how-to-solve-the-pytorch-runtimeerror-numpy-is-not-available-without-upgrading

Please give your code so we can reproduce your issue
